# Find Novatec hub model based on inscribed (serial) number

Tags: parts, hub, serial-number

I bought a second-hand bike. My bike's rear hub has no sticker indicating what it is, but there is a number, namely T05100300014, written on it, maybe a serial number. Could I use this to find what model it is? Google yields nothing, but I am awaiting a reply from Novatec at the moment (since my bike model should have a hub from them).

Note: my front hub also has a number of the same format (starting with "T" and with the same number of digits, I think) and that does have a Novatec sticker.

Comment: I don't know how the Novatec serial numbers correspond to the model numbers, but they do typically or perhaps always have a freehub body model number stamped on the freehub splines, which is the key piece of information in the event of needing a freehub, i.e. the most common scenario where the model number is relevant. For Novatec in particular, you can find their old catalogs online pretty easy. Usually figuring out model numbers and freehub compatibility etc is possible with them, but requires a brute force approach of looking through the catalogs.

Comment: What's your goal here?  Are you looking for replacement bearings or something ?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I will try looking for the catalogs. I want to know so that I can be sure it's the original hub, though I was given no reason to doubt it.